# Override ionic variable intel XDK, all the icone are not displaying

Tags: sass, ionic-framework, intel-xdk

I am using Intel XDK to use develop ionic app. I wanted to override the default color variables for ionic. I followed the followings steps exactally:

[Writing a Sass Theme](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/working-with-sass/)

and finally `gulp sass` command to complile sass.

I got the my desired color for balanced variable, but all the ionic icons are not displaying

[image: ![my start and cart icons are not displaying]

I do not know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use custom CSS elements to overwrite color properties.  Use Intel xdk console to inspect the element first then create a custom css for that element.

Comment: I used ionic positive at 100 places, do you want me to do changes on all those 100 places

Comment: inspecting the element on test mode you can get ionic class of the element. this will give you the exact class of the element with your custom CSS file create the style desired for the element you want to change. it will automatically apply the overwrite style to all elements as you reference the existing element property class.